# Exchange 2007: Is there a way to get average number of attachements per day by file type?

Tags: exchange-2007, metrics

I'm curious about the file formats of attachments moving through an Exchange 2007 mail environment.  For instance the number of .doc vs. .docx files on average.  Exchange Profile Analyzer seems more geared to message size than anything else.  Is there anything that can provide this information without being hugely intrusive?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.mapilab.com/exchange/reports_exchange/) would seem to meet your criteria.  I've never used it, but it might be worth your time to check out.